# Can I create a WMI filter that will evaluate to True for both Client computers and Terminal Servers?

Tags: group-policy, wmi

I have a GPO that is currently being run only on client computers (XP, Vista, 7, etc.), by using a WMI filter with the following query:

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where ProductType='1'
```

I would like to include Terminal Servers in this filter, but the best check for a Terminal Server appears to be in a different class (and namespace for Server 2008+). This requires a second, and possibly third, query to be added to the filter:

```
Select * From Win32_TerminalServiceSetting Where TerminalServerMode='1'
```

Unfortunately, these queries appear to AND together, resulting in the filter always evaluating to False, and I cannot find an option to change that. Is it possible to get this down to one filter with multiple queries, or will I need to create multiple filters, thus multiple GPOs?